# BigCommerce Custom Fields to affect price

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

This is for a BigCommerce site. I need to collect delivery date information per product so am adding a jQuery datepicker along with some radio buttons for customers to choose their desired date of delivery. (See Screen Shot).

I'm wondering if it's possible to assign on a monetary value for each of the choices that will be added to the total product price and, once the order is submitted, have the chosen option passed on along with the other order details.

I'm not sure if it's very relevant but pasted my HTML and the datepicker code as well.

Disclaimers: I am not familiar with the BigCommerce API but am willing to give it a try if that's the only way. Otherwise some jQuery or javascript is what I was told might be my best option. However, I'm new at both so, if that is the way to go, please be as specific as possible with your responses. Much appreciated.

[image]

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //holidays
    var natDays = [
      [1, 1, 'New Year'], //2014
      [1, 20, 'Martin Luther King'], //2014
      [2, 17, 'Washingtons Birthday'], //2014       
      [5, 26, 'Memorial Day'], //2014
      [7, 4, 'Independence Day'], //2014
      [9, 1, 'Labour Day'], //2014
      [10, 14, 'Columbus Day'], //2013
      [11, 11, 'Veterans Day'], //2013
      [11, 28, 'Thanks Giving Day'], //2013 
      [12, 25, 'Christmas'] //2013     
];

    var dateMin = new Date();
    dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() + (dateMin.getHours() >= 14 ? 1 : 0));
    AddBusinessDays(dateMin, 4);

    function AddBusinessDays(curdate, weekDaysToAdd) {
        while (weekDaysToAdd > 0) {
            curdate.setDate(curdate.getDate() + 1);
            //check if current day is business day
            if (noWeekendsOrHolidays(curdate)[0]) {
                weekDaysToAdd--;
            }
        }
    }    

    function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
        var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
        if (noWeekend[0]) {
            return nationalDays(date);
        } else {
            return noWeekend;
        }
    }
    function nationalDays(date) {
        for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
            if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
                return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];
    }
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
            inline: true,
            beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,           
            showOn: "both",            
            firstDay: 0,
                dateformat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeFirstDay: false,
            showButtonPanel: true,       
            minDate: dateMin            
    });
  });
  </script>

<p>
<label for="datepicker">Desired Delivery Date: </label>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="ex. 01/01/2013" name="properties[Delivery Date]" readonly />
  <label><font size=1>Need it faster? Call us! (800) 880-0307</font>
  </label></p>
<style>
  #datepicker { height: 17px; max-width: 120px; }
  #datepicker {-webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0; -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0; border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;}
</style>
```

HTML FOR RADIO OPTIONS:

```
 <p style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 40px;"><font size=3>Please Choose From Delivery Options:</font></p>   
    <br>                                                             
    <label for="Standard" style=" margin-left: 40px;">
    <input id="Standard" type="radio" name="properties[Delivery]" value="Standard Shipping" />
    <font>Standard Shipping</font><br>
    <p>
    <font size=1 style="margin-left: 18px;">Earliest Date of Delivery: 
    <span id="delivery-date">Estimated Date from Datepicker</span></font>
    </p>
    </label>
    {datepicker goes here}                                   
    <hr style=" margin-left: 40px;"> 
     <br>                                                            
     <label for="3DayExpress" style=" margin-left: 40px;">
     <input id="3DayExpress" type="radio"name="properties[Delivery]" value="3Day Express" />
     <font>Guaranteed by <script>document.write(d_names[curr_day] + " " + m_names[curr_month] + " " + curr_date + "<SUP>"
                                + sup + "</SUP> " + curr_year);</script>.<br></font><font size=1 style="margin-left: 18px;">3 Day Express Shipping. Additional $15</font>                  </label>
    <br>                                                             
    <label for="2DayExpress" style=" margin-left: 40px;">
    <input id="2DayExpress" type="radio" name="properties[Delivery]" value="2Day Express" />
    <font>Guaranteed by <script>document.write(d_names[curr_day] + " " + m_names[curr_month] + " " + curr_date + "<SUP>"
                                + sup + "</SUP> " + curr_year);</script>.<br></font><font size=1 style="margin-left: 18px;">2 Day Express Shipping. Additional $25</font>
   </label><br>
```

Comment: What is that JS from anyway?  Doesn't look like BC.